# Drop-down Jump Menu Issue (random %08 in URL)

Tags: javascript, html, menu, backspace

I've got the following select menu that builds a dynamic url based on the selected value.
All values work well, except for the value "1" (i.e. 1995-96).
The variable is correctly identified (page.php?SeasonId=1), however, the page then sends to page.php?SeasonId=%081

Notice the extra %08 which I believe is a backspace?
Where is that coming from and how can I get rid of it? I'm stumped!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("select").selectric({
            onChange: function(){
                var go_to = "page.php?SeasonId=" + $("select option:selected").val();
                window.location.href = go_to;
            }
        });
    });
</script>

    <select>
        <option value="" selected="selected">Season</option>
        <option value="18">2013-14</option>
        <option value="17">2012-13</option>
        <option value="16">2011-12</option>
        <option value="15">2010-11</option>
        <option value="14">2009-10</option>
        <option value="13">2008-09</option>
        <option value="12">2007-08</option>
        <option value="11">2006-07</option>
        <option value="10">2005-06</option>
        <option value="9">2003-04</option>
        <option value="8">2002-03</option>
        <option value="7">2001-02</option>
        <option value="6">2000-01</option>
        <option value="5">1999-00</option>
        <option value="4">1998-99</option>
        <option value="3">1997-98</option>
        <option value="2">1996-97</option>
        <option value="1">1995-96</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Set up your IDE to show all characters and remove the character. OR delete the line and retype it.

Comment: Found it! I feel like an idiot... Thanks @epascarello